# Open a dropbox folder from my android application

Tags: android, android-intent, android-widget, dropbox, dropbox-api

I want to do something like the Android Dropbox widget that opens a specific Dropbox folder. For example, onclick event, open my photos Dropbox folder, not a chooser but a view of the folder using the Dropbox application. Any ideas ? Thanks.

Comment: There currently isn't an API to do this, but we're tracking it as a feature request.

Comment: Thanks @Greg for the answer, are you by any change related to Dropbox team, I kinda need such info to back my argument with my client, appreciate it :)

Comment: Yes, I'm a Developer Advocate for the Dropbox Developer Platform team.

Comment: Thank you and looking forward to using the feature soon :)